# Distinct rows with Summation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have EXPENSE table.

```
DECLARE @EXPENSE TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    CURRENCY NVARCHAR(4),
    AMOUNT   MONEY
)

INSERT INTO @EXPENSE VALUES
(1,'USD',100),
(2,'USD',10),
(1,'USD',80),
(2,'USD',5),
(1,'EUR',80),
(1,'EUR',30),
(3,'USD',20)
```

The data is shown below:

```
+----+----------+--------+
| ID | CURRENCY | AMOUNT |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | USD      | 100    |
+----+----------+--------+
| 2  | USD      | 10     |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | USD      | 80     |
+----+----------+--------+
| 2  | USD      | 5      |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | EUR      | 80     |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | EUR      | 30     |
+----+----------+--------+
| 3  | USD      | 20     |
+----+----------+--------+
```

I would like to get the result like this.

```
+----+----------+--------+
| ID | CURRENCY | AMOUNT |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | EUR      | 110    |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | USD      | 180    |
+----+----------+--------+
| 2  | USD      | 15     |
+----+----------+--------+
| 2  | EUR      | 0      |
+----+----------+--------+
| 3  | USD      | 20     |
+----+----------+--------+
| 3  | EUR      | 0      |
+----+----------+--------+
```

I wrote the following:

```
SELECT E.ID, E.CURRENCY, SUM(E.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
FROM @EXPENSE AS E
GROUP BY E.ID, E.CURRENCY
```

But it does not give me missing currency and zero amounts.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: I think what's missing from your description is that you also want to maintain placeholders for Currency type and Amount. So there will always be the two Currency types (USD, EUR), but they won't always necessarily have an amount, in which case, you want it to default to 0. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `CROSS` join of the distinct ids and the distinct currencies and then a `LEFT` join to the table to aggregate:

```
SELECT i.ID, c.CURRENCY,
       COALESCE(SUM(AMOUNT), 0) TOTAL
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM @EXPENSE) i
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CURRENCY FROM @EXPENSE) c
LEFT JOIN @EXPENSE e ON e.ID = i.ID AND e.CURRENCY = c.CURRENCY
GROUP BY i.ID, c.CURRENCY
ORDER BY i.ID, c.CURRENCY
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4a70d47a2c35475d1ddf2f4fab4d79d5).
Results:

```
> ID | CURRENCY |    TOTAL
> -: | :------- | -------:
>  1 | EUR      |    110
>  1 | USD      |    180
>  2 | EUR      |      0
>  2 | USD      |     15
>  3 | EUR      |      0
>  3 | USD      |     20
```